# Read preference of other application android

Tags: android, preferences

i've read that shared preferences can be retrieved from outside my application .
this code did not work:

```
try 
{
    myContext = createPackageContext("com.intervigil.micdroid", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE); // where com.example is the owning  app containing the preferences
    SharedPreferences testPrefs = myContext.getSharedPreferences("test_prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); 
    Map<String, ?> items = testPrefs.getAll();
    nbenroullement= (Integer) items.get("enroullement");
    System.out.println("*********************" + nbenroullement);
} 
catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please can any one help me . Thank you

Comment: In what way did the code not work? Did it throw a `NameNotFoundException` or another kind of exception or just didn't find the value you were looking for?

Comment: I didn't find the value of my sharedpreference

Comment: Show the code where you get the shared preferences and store the `enroullement` key in `test_prefs` inside the application with the package `com.intervigil.micdroid`

Comment: By the way, createPackageContext does not accept the flag Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE, look at the method in the official documentation.

Comment: please show this code where i set the value of the enrollement  in the first application Editor edit = sp.edit();
      int nbenroullement = sp.getInt("enroullement", 0);
      edit.putInt("enroullement", nbenroullement + 1);
      edit.commit();

Comment: i change this ligne by is on Context otherAppsContext = createPackageContext(
       "com.intervigil.micdroid", 0);

Answer (score 1):

Finaly i get the solution in this tutorial 
I hope that i help you 
http://androiddhamu.blogspot.in/2012/03/share-data-across-application-in.html

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you aren't itereting the Maps `items`. 
So, try to do something like that :

```
Map<String, ?> items = testPrefs .getAll();
for(String s : items.keySet()){
    String value =  items.get(s).toString()); //this is the key of preferences

}
```

Once you retrieve the key (enroullement, I presume) you got to use it like this :

```
enroullement = Integer.valueOf(prefs.getString("enroullement", "0")); //0 is a default value
```

Hope it helps.